# Let $q_n, n=1,2,3,\ldots$ be on stringing of rational numbers from $[0,1]$.

Tags: probability, number-theory, limits, probability-theory

$a.) $Let $q_n, n=1,2,3,\ldots$ be on stringing of rational numbers from $[0,1]$ and let the be given a sequence of sets: $A_n=[q_n,1] n=1,2,3,\ldots$ Find $$\overline{\lim_{n\to \infty}} A_n.$$

Now this $n\to \infty$ isn't quite given but I can only pressume that I must be the case so I feel I should do the assignment like , because similar has been done in class: $$\overline{\lim_{n\to \infty}} A_n= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k.$$

Can someone formally type out the answer, if possible using this method?

$b.)$ And basically the same question: 
Let $q_n,\ n=1,2,3,\ldots$ be on stringing of rational numbers from $[0,1]$ and let the be given a sequence of sets: $A_n=[0,q_n],\ n=1,2,3,\ldots$ Find $$\underline{\lim} A_n.$$ Here in what I think are similar examples we did: $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k.$$

Comment: By "on stringing of rational numbers" do you mean a list that includes each rational?

Comment: Yes, I do meant that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for the first problem: Let $n$ be given, and let $\epsilon\gt 0$. Then there is a $k\gt n$ such that $q_k\lt \epsilon$. What does that say about $\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$?

**Added:** We first show that for all $n$ there is a $k\gt n$ such that $q_k\lt \epsilon$. This is because there are infinitely many rationals in the interval $0\lt x\lt \epsilon$, and there are only $n$ rationals of the form $q_i$ where $i\le n$.

So for every $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is a $k\gt n$ such that $[\epsilon,1]\subset A_k$. It follows that $\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ contains the interval $(0,1]$. For every large enough $n$, $\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ does not contain $0$. We conclude that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k=(0,1]$.

Hint for the second problem: Use the fact that for every $n$, and for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is a $k\gt m$ such that $q_k\gt 1-\epsilon$.

Comment: Could you type it out if you don;t mind me asking, because we have not done any questions like these, and I don;t have much confidence doing them to be honest

Comment: I'll give it a read soon, im busy at the moment, thanks for adding detail.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Im confused with the following : $\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}A_i \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_i, k>1$ so shouldnt the intersection be $\to 1$??

Comment: $\bigcup_{i=k}^{\infty} A_i= A_k $ and $A_{k+1} \subset A_{k}$

Comment: This I mean for  $  a.) $

Comment: because $q_n$ is the first rational after 0 , am I right? Idk ?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: We will ultimately be taking an intersection, so we need to know the points that are un $\cup_{k=n} A_k$ for **all** $n$, That it is a subset of $\cup{k=1} A_k$ is not useful. The why for all $n$ there is a $k\gt n$ such that $0\lt q_k\lt \epsilon$ is explained in the post. There are infinitely many rationals in $(0,\epsilon)$, and no matter how far we have gone in the list $q_1,q_2,\dots$, we have only listed finitely many rationals, so there are infinitely many rationals in $(0,\epsilon)$ not yet listed.

Comment: i'm aware that there are infinitely many rationals not listed in $(0, \epsilon)$ What is unclear is how this intersection could possibly be (0,1] when you've got for example $\bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty} A_i \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_i$ for the intersection here is $\bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty} A_i$... and so on so it looks like the intersection should be to me $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_{n}^{\infty } A_n $ for all, what am I not seeing ??

Comment: Recall that $A_k=[q_k,1]$. Let $\epsilon_i=\frac{1}{2^i}$, and fix $n$. There is a $k_1\gt n$ such that $q_{k_1}\lt \epsilon_1$, So all of $[\epsilon_1,1]$ is a subset of $\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$. Similarly, all of $[\epsilon_2,1]$ is a subset of $\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$. And all of $[\epsilon_3,1]$ and so on. The union of the $[\epsilon_i,1]$ is all of $(0,1]$, so all of $(0,1]$ is a subset of $\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$.  And of course there is no more, so $\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k=(0,1]$.

Comment: what about the intersection of these unions ?

Comment: Every union, as shown above, is $(0,1]$ so the intersection of the unions is $(0,1]$.

Comment: I cant wrap my head around the fact that every union is $(0,1]$. What if you take a rational:$ q_n= 1/2+ \epsilon$ how is the $\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}[q_n, 1]=(0,1]$ it looks like to me that it is $(1/2+ \epsilon , 1]$. I really want to understand this. :) :)

Comment: From the deinition of $A_k$ it makes no difference at all.

Comment: What I'm saying is if $q_i=\frac{1}{2}$ and from this I see $\bigcup_{k=i}^{\infty}[q_i, 1]=(\frac{1}{2},1] \neq (0,1]$ this is a contradiction to what you say, what am I not understanding? I feel like I am close to seeing the answer, this is where the problem lys in my understanding

Comment: If $q_n=1/2$, then of course $A_n=[1/2,1}$. But there is an $i\gt n$ such that $q_i\lt 1/100$, so that $A_i$ contains $[1/100,1]$ and possibly more. And there is also a $j\gt n$ such that $q_j\lt 1/1000$, and that $A_j$ contains at least $[1/1000,1]$. And so on.So the union $\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ contains $[1/2,1]$, also $[1/100,1]$, also  $[1/1000,1]$, and so on. So this union contains every number $\gt 0$ and $\le 1$.

Comment: I see , I thought the union started from the number that you initializes n with, and also that that all $k>n$ meant $A_k \subset A_n$

Comment: or that $q_k > q_n (k>n)$ because I thought the series was ordered from smallest rational on $(0,1)$ to largest , thinking $q_1$ was the first rational after $0$

Comment: It is impossible to enumerate the rationals as $q_1,q_2,q_3,\dots$ so that the ordering has anything significant in common with the "natural" order. In particular, there is no way to arrange to have $A_k\subset A_n$ whenever $k\gt n$.  For any enumeration $q_1,q_2,\dots$ of the rationals, if you visit $q_1$ then $q_2$ and so on you will be jumping wildly forever.